# Typescript: type system cannot prove something that seems obviously true

Tags: typescript

The following gives a compile error in `getWrapper`:

```
type Wrapper<K> = {
    value: K
}

type Wrappers = {
    [K in 'henk' | 'piet']: Wrapper<K>
}
const wrappers: Wrappers = {
    'henk': { value: 'henk' },
    'piet': { value: 'piet' }
}

function getWrapper<K extends keyof Wrappers>(k: K): Wrapper<K> {
    return wrappers[k]
}
```

It says dat that `wrappers[k]` is `Wrapper<'henk'> | Wrapper<'piet'>`. It should be able figure out that `wrappers[k]` is actually `Wrapper<K>`. Can I help Typescript to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: 2019-05-30 the release of TypeScript 3.5 introduces [smarter union type checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking) but it does not fix this issue, likely because this is using a generic type `K` instead of a union of known concrete types.  So there's no change to the solution below as of now.

---

I'm pretty sure that your problem is that [TypeScript doesn't reduce unions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289) the way you expect.  For example, you might expect the following to work:

```
declare const innerUnion: { foo: string | number };
const outerUnion: { foo: string } | { foo: number } = iU; // error
```

But it doesn't.  TypeScript does not aggressively reduce the type of `outerUnion` to the type of `innerUnion`.  The reason the compiler doesn't do this automatically seems to be pragmatism: in many cases such a reduction is wrong because there's another property that can't be merged:

```
declare const iU: { foo: string | number, bar: string | number };
const oU: { foo: string, bar: string } | { foo: number, bar: string } = iU; // error
```

The above error is a good one, since perhaps `iU` is `{ foo: 0, bar: '' }`.

TypeScript thinks `K` can be of type `'henk' | 'piet'`, and therefore the output of the function could be `Wrapper<'henk' | 'piet'>`, but the return value is of type `Wrapper<'henk'> | Wrapper<'piet'>`.  And since the above union reduction is something TypeScript doesn't do, it says there's an error.

---

So, *why* does the return value have type `Wrapper<'henk'> | Wrapper<'piet'>`?  Because indexing into objects with a union of keys *does* result in the union of the property values of that object.

This suggests a solution to your problem, use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to represent that indexing operation:

```
function getWrapper<K extends keyof Wrappers>(k: K): Wrappers[K] {
    return wrappers[k]; // okay
}
```

This does what you want, I think.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That's a very thorough answer! Thank you!

Conceptually, I have one question left. Because it knows a little more about `Wrappers` than that it just has keys and values. It knows (or should know) that to every key `K` belongs a value `Wrapper<K>`. Why doesn't it use this information, instead saying that "all I know about the value is that it is either `Wrapper<'henk'>` or `Wrapper<'piet'>`?

Comment: I can fool the code with ```function getWrapper<K extends keyof Wrappers>(k: K): Wrappers[K] {
    return { value: 'piet' }
}```, so it doesn't really work, unfortunately.

Comment: The value of the `K` parameter can be `'henk' | 'piet'`.  Here, look: `getWrapper(Math.random()<0.5 ? 'henk' : 'piet')`.

Comment: As for fooling the code in the *implementation* of the function, that seems to be a different issue and maybe one worthy of submitting as a TS bug.

Comment: "The value of the K parameter can be 'henk' | 'piet'. Here, look: getWrapper(Math.random()<0.5 ? 'henk' : 'piet')" Yeah, but we know (even inside `getWrapper`) that whatever `K` is when we call the function, we know that what we get a `Wrapper<...>` for the *exact same* `K`. Or am I missing something really dumb?